# My iterm2 can only use basic colors

Tags: iterm2

my iterm2 can only use basic colors.. I had tried the following 2 tricks but neither of them worked:

1. set the "minimum contrast" to low
2. set the report terminal type to "xterm-256color" (echo $TERM shows: xterm-256color)

any other suggestions? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the `solarized` color scheme from [Here](https://github.com/altercation/solarized/tree/master/iterm2-colors-solarized)

Import to your profile then `Load Preset` select `dark background` or `light background`.

I only have a basic color setup for command line prompts, see following picture.

[image]

If you want more fancy setups, have a look at this page [Bash prompt](http://www.askapache.com/linux/bash-power-prompt.html)
Or checkout Zsh schemes [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh)

Following is the section related to my command prompt in my .bash_profile file. I am also using Solarized color scheme for my iTerm2, keep that in mind.

```
  BLACK='\e[0;30m'
  BLUE='\e0;34m'
  BROWN='\e[0;33m'
  CYAN='\e[0;36m'
  DARKGRAY='\e[1;30m'
  GRAY='\e[0;37m'
  GREEN='\e[32m'
  LIGHTBLUE='\e[1;34m'
  LIGHTCYAN='\e[1;36m'
  LIGHTGRAY='\e[0;37m'
  LIGHTGREEN='\e[1;32m'
  LIGHTPURPLE='\e[1;35m'
  LIGHTRED='\e[1;31m'
  PURPLE='\e[0;35'
  RED='\e[0;31m'
  YELLOW='\e[1;33m'
  NC='\e[m'

  PS1="\`if [[ \$EUID -eq 0 ]]; then PCT='\[$LIGHTRED\]';
  else PCT='\[$LIGHTCYAN\]'; fi;
  echo '\[$NC\]['\$PCT'\u\[$YELLOW\]@\[$GREEN\]\h:\w\[$NC\]]\[$GRAY\] : \[$NC\]'\`"
```

Comment: Just tried. Looks like the color scheme is only for scripts, right? Is there a way to change the colors for command and output? Ex: If I type "cd ~/foo/foo2", cd and ~/foo/foo2 will be in different colors

Comment: Updated my answer based on your comment

Comment: @AskandLearn I'm trying to get the type of hilighting shown in your picture and Ive tried what you recommended, but still no luck. What else would you recommend?

Comment: @user1596679 You need to define those colors in your .bash_profile file and then configure you `PS1` variable to use them. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't the solarized theme automatically do this in iterm? This worked perfectly on my work computer but none of the bash colors show up on my home computer unless I explicitly define them in bash_profile